# Retrieving data when a meta_key is stored as a date()

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, function

I have a wordpress site which in the database has meta_keys which are being stored as dates:

```
update_user_meta( $current_user, date('l jS F Y'), $serialized_data);
```

What I need to do is retrieve all meta_values where the meta_key is a date (regardless of what the date is), something like :

```
get_user_meta( $current_user->ID, any_date() , $value );
```

Is this possible am i able to recoginse a field as a date field or will it have to be done another way?

Thanks for any help

David

Comment: those aren't dates. they're strings that contain some characters that LOOK like dates to humans. that's also the KEY to identify which value you want. keys should be fixed/known quantities. How will you be able to tell which key you want?  because you'd have to know WHEN you stored that value in the first place.

Comment: Thanks for the reply , could you advise on how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use MySQL's [str_to_date() function](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date) to return a date, datetime, or time data out of a properly formatted string. The function returns null, if the data does not match the format string. Jut make sure you translate the date format string (`'l jS F Y'`) to MySQL's own syntax.

To get the dates only, you can do sg like the following (make sure you adjust the pattern for your needs!!!!):

```
SELECT STR_TO_DATE(your_field,'%d,%m,%Y')
FROM your_table
HAVING STR_TO_DATE(your_field,'%d,%m,%Y') IS NOT NULL;
```